# Completely locked out of root in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When trying to start mysql, I receive the following error message:

> ERROR 3118 (HY000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Account is locked.

I've installed MySQL via homebrew on my OSX and have not encountered such an issue until yesterday.  When I try to run `mysqld_safe`, I receive:

> mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/****.pid ended.

If I try `sudo mysqld stop`, I receive:

> Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

I am unable to `sudo restart mysql.server` as I receive:

> ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

I looked into running a data dump of my db but I am prevented from doing this as well.

Thanks for your attention to this matter and any insight you can provide in this matter.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: FYI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: Who said the topicstarter is using ubuntu? @marekful "I've installed MySQL via homebrew on my **OSX**", but sure the Mac OS and linux have the same terminal commands more or less. Not sure if Mac OS uses `su` or `sudo` or the same general directory structure which linux has

Comment: Thank you both for your responses, marekful and @raymond nijland.  I appreciate you being so quick to respond.  Unfortunately, I receive the 'locked' message when I try to use sudo as well:  sudo mysql stop
ERROR 3118 (HY000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Account is locked.